# java how to center a string in the middle of the frame

Tags: java

Hello I have a programme that displays a number. I want the number to be in the centre of the frame. The number increases and decreases and gets un-centred.
How can I centre a string to the middle of the frame:

```
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.drawString(""+play.metal, Comp.size.width /2,35);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int len = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(myString);
g.drawString(myString, Comp.size.width-len/2, 35);
```